# «В больницу Вы попав не дали мне...» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, деепричастный-оборот, поэзия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, совы, как правильно этот деепричастный оборот обособить-таки?
У меня с этим серьёзные проблемы, и я вообще не понимаю, как это сделать, так как *Вы* — это и часть деепричастного оборота, и подлежащее главного предложения таки.

*В больницу **Вы** попав не дали мне ничего, что б означало... между нами будет что-то.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похожая ситуация описывается-таки у мудрого Розенталя.

> **Примечание.** <...> У поэтов-классиков встречаются деепричастные обороты, включающие в свой состав подлежащее, которое не выделяется внутри оборота запятыми: ***Услышав** граф **её походку и проклиная свой ночлег и своенравную красотку,** в постыдный обратился бег* (П.); ***На ель** Ворона **взгромоздясь,** позавтракать было совсем уж собралась* (Кр.); ***…Старосту лизнув** Лев **милостиво в грудь,** отправился в дальнейший путь* (Кр); ***Сатиров** я **для помощи призвав,** подговорю, и всё пойдёт на лад* (Л.)...

Надо поставить запятую после оборота:
***В больницу** Вы **попав,** не дали мне ничего, что б означало... между нами будет что-то.*

С претензией на классику, думаю, нужно бы написать так:

*В больницу Вы попав, не дали ничего,

что б означало — между нами будет что-то.*

[Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112) (п. 4)